# Switching between different batteries!

Tags: power, batteries, switch-mode-power-supply

I Have got a project wherein I have to achieve this!

[image]

Please neglect the charger set up for my block diagram.

Since I am a newbie to electronics, I am unable to get any idea how I would switch between different batteries to obtain uninterrupted power supply. I have refered to similiar quetion wherein someone asked the same thing for 5V batteries. But I do need this at some large level,where my current ratings are close to 1.5A and 15-20V supply.I wont be siple able to use normal ICs or relays. Whatever ideas I had thought they were proved wrong as they didnt followed up my suppy specification. Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

1.5A and 20V is not a large amount of current or voltage. It's peanuts. You don't need anything "special".

Since we don't know your actual requirements (you neglect to mention the things we need in your pretty picture), we can only make vague suggestions and surmises.

- **First surmise:** It looks like you might want the external DC supply to be used in preference to the battery bank.
- **Second surmise:** The external DC voltage is higher than the battery bank voltage.
- **Third surmise:** You are regulating the voltages to a usable level.

If those surmises are true, then you should just be able to use a pair of diodes (Schottky for preference) to select the higher voltage supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKX04V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If those surmises are not correct then you will probably have to come up with an active switching system, most likely involving a P-channel MOSFET, an op-amp, and a voltage divider.

Comment: You'd normally use a schottky in this topology to save a little power. Make sure the diode is rated for the current draw.

Comment: CircuitLab doesn't seem to have a schottky symbol, or I'd have used one.

Comment: Scratch that - found it. Edit the diode and change the display dropdown. Personally I'd have had a separate symbol, like there is for the zenner.

Comment: Be aware though that Schottky do tend to have higher reverse leakage current.

Comment: Very true, I learned that the hard way once. Leakage current in the mA range! Gotta spec it carefully.